# Isomorphisms from $K_5$ to points in $\mathbb R^4$

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

Is there an isomorphism from the complete graph $K_5$ to a triangular solid in $\mathbb R^4$?

For example $K_3$ is trivially mapped to a triangle,
$K_4$ may be mapped to a tetrahedron, so what about $K_5$?

Does this mean that for any $K_n$ there exists an isomorphism from $K_n$ to a triangular solid in $\mathbb R^{n-1}$?

Comment: Did you mean isomorphism from $K_n$ to a triangular solid in $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$?

Comment: (Also, the wikipedia entry for [simplex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex) might help.)

Comment: Yes, thank you very much Dennis!